# Let's get critical: Oct 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Pets Stack Exchange](http://pets.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://pets.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Comment: More than half of the supplied questions and answers had poor grammar.  For the sake of the self-evaluation, I corrected none of them.

Comment: @JoshDM Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214761/should-i-improve-posts-that-are-part-of-the-site-self-evaluation-or-wait-until-t

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Do mosquitoes bite reptiles? Is there any danger of communicating pathogens?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6267/do-mosquitoes-bite-reptiles-is-there-any-danger-of-communicating-pathogens)

**Net Score: 7** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How can one judge the quality of puppy classes?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6201/how-can-one-judge-the-quality-of-puppy-classes)

**Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 8, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [My Cat is missing hair on her neck](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6303/my-cat-is-missing-hair-on-her-neck)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 9, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [What is a hound?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6151/what-is-a-hound)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How smart are rabbits?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6281/how-smart-are-rabbits)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Can cats see equally well in both light and dark?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6157/can-cats-see-equally-well-in-both-light-and-dark)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [Cat always tries to eat chives](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6238/cat-always-tries-to-eat-chives)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 9, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Why do cats lick their front paws thorougly after eating?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6248/why-do-cats-lick-their-front-paws-thorougly-after-eating)

**Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [How can I get my cat to stop nursing from its mother?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6228/how-can-i-get-my-cat-to-stop-nursing-from-its-mother)

**Net Score: -4** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [On average, when do cats stop producing milk after giving birth?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6229/on-average-when-do-cats-stop-producing-milk-after-giving-birth)

**Net Score: -5** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 6)

---

Comment: The scores seem significantly lower than the previous evaluations.

Comment: @MattS. - They do, I don't know if that's luck of the draw or if there has been a degradation in quality. That's the hard thing to determine in this process.

Comment: Given that each question only has about a dozen votes, it is very hard to draw a statistical conclusion as to whether this is truly a lower result.  Perhaps we need more encouragement to get people reviewing next time.